# Как подружиться с nVidia видеокартой в Ubuntu 16.04 (чёрный экран)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, nvidia

Ноутбук DELL Inspiron n5110. После установки Ubuntu (Gnome) радостно встретила меня черным экраном.

Проверил оперативку (memtest), жёсткий диск (badblocks), начал грешить на видеокарту.

Поставил драйвера последние, актуальные (nVidia GT 525M) и ждало меня разочарование: NVIDIA X Server Settings не видит монитор, никаких настроек выставить не могу, хотя активирована nvidia карта.

Почитал форумы, руководства, решения не нашел. Может, есть знающие люди, готовые подсказать, что делать?

UPD. Т.е. при установленном свободном драйвере nouveau после установки gnome на чистой системе вылазит черный экран. Может, вообще проблема не в драйвере?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](http://askubuntu.com/q/760374/3712) (KMS только в самых последних драйверах nvidia (364.12+)появилось, попробуйте nomodeset выставить, как в ссылке рекомендуют—эффект в том, что до запуска X, разрешение в консоли маленькое). На будущее: проверять совместимость железа лучше *до* установки.

Comment: @jfs спс за ссылку, сейчас попробую. При Unity проблем никаких нет вообще, видео играется, игры правда никакие не пробовал, а вот когда поставил gnome-shell и выбрал gdm после перезагрузки появились симптомы. Поэтому и была мысль, что железо сошлось, тем более, что оно далеко не новое и драйвер тоже не свежак, последний на сайте nVidia стоит 367, а в репе доступен только 361.